How to delete offset when message got consumed using franz-go?
I'm using franz-go library to implement the kafka
Case want to achieve :- I want to delete the message from kafka when it get consumed using adminClient
Error :- map[] request key is unknown
Code
func consumeMessages(ctx context.Context, client *kgo.Client, adminClient *kadm.Client) {
    for {
        fetches := client.PollFetches(ctx)
        if errs := fetches.Errors(); len(errs) > 0 {
            panic(fmt.Sprint(errs))
        }
        fmt.Println("reached")

        // Iterate through a record iterator...
        iter := fetches.RecordIter()
        for !iter.Done() {
            record := iter.Next()
            fmt.Println(string(record.Value), "from an iterator!")

            partitionMap := map[int32]struct{}{record.Partition: {}}
            topicMap := map[string]map[int32]struct{}{record.Topic: partitionMap}

            // Delete offsets using the admin client.
            dresp, err := adminClient.DeleteOffsets(ctx, "my-group-identifier", topicMap)
            fmt.Println(dresp, err) // here is the error 
        }
    }
} 

Help will be appriciated
